# execute python file from another file

Tags: python, import, exec

I have a python file that has functions and classes. now I am writting another program (in another file). and I want to start the new file with running the old file (with the function and classes). I have tried using exec(path_2_oldFile.pyw) but it didn't work.

thanks for any help
Ariel

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should try and import the first file into the new as a module using the `import` statement:

http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

You'll need to make sure that your original module is on the python path somewhere. If it is in the same directory as the new file this should just work.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to use it as a module, I want to run it (like F5 does in idle).